# popen Hangs and cause CPU usage to 100

Tags: c++, c

I have a code that use popen to execute a script ,It works fine but randomly it's blocking and getting CPU to 100% ,after a little investigation I discover that it hangs on popen calls. I have put a printf after the popen showing the descriptor asigned and in this case when it blocks this printf never shows.

What can cause popen to block?

Edit: Code

```
FILE* pipe = popen(cpCommand, "r");
        printf(....               
        if (pipe)
        {
                while (!feof(pipe))
                {
                        if (DataReady(fileno(pipe),2500)>0)
                        {
                                if (fgets(output,sizeof(output),pipe) != NULL)
                                {
```

DataReady is just a select..
I have done a strace after it blocks and it seems to not doing anything

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: You do terminate with a `\n` what is `printf()`ed out after the call to `popen()`, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer ;-)

1. Try use `strace` to what it's doing and which syscall hangs.
2. Tterminal output is line-buffered, so make sure to flush output by using fflush() or using a newline (`fflush(stdout);` or `printf("Debug text\n");`) to ensure it doesn't really call the printf().
3. Run the script manually and ensure the script doesn't hang intermittently before suspecting popen().

Answer (score 0):

Check the script called by `popen()` why it doesn't end.

As long a s the script does not end, `popen()` blocks, will say: does not return, as observed.

---

I strongly doubt this is a C issue.

Comment: I know but it usually works, after 1 or 2 days is when it get blocked, and also in this moment the script runs perfectly.